# Can we invent a machine that produce more force than it takes with levers?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

For example, a heavy object is lifted by levers and dropped, producing energy with the force of falling (gravity + object), and that heavy object is lifted with less force than it produces, using levers, Can this be possible?

Comment: Please take a look to make sure my edit made sense with what you wanted.  I believe you meant that the object is lifted with less force than it produces.

Comment: Yes, my english is not very good.

Comment: I've seen much worse than that.  I was able to understand it enough to fix it, so it really wasn't that bad.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Are you asking if it is possible to create unlimited amounts of free energy by using less energy to lift them up than the energy which they release when they fall?

Comment: Well not unlimited, but some extra energy, that maybe it will stops one day and needs external energy to work again, i ask if that's possible, using less force by using levers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Feynman Lectures: Why a non-reversible weight lifting machine cannot lift higher that a reversible one?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190738)

Comment: What do you mean by "some extra energy"? Do you mean that we get more energy out than we put in?

Comment: Yes that, the heavy object produces more force than it takes lifting it with levers

Comment: When you say "force" you mean "energy" right? For example you want to raise a heavy object using 100J of energy using levers, then let it fall down and release say 101J of energy.

Comment: Yes, i'm asking if that's possible, using levers, because with them you can raise a heavy object with less force, or energy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104389/discussion-between-jose-garcia-and-sammy-gerbil).

Answer (score 1):

no it is not possible. When you lift a mass with a lever an use only say 1/5 of its weight yo can lift it only 1/5 of the height you could lift ist with the fullforcd, so it would drop only 1/5 of the way an you do not gain any energy. The golden rule of mechanics says: the smaller the force, the longer the way of the force, so to lift something a d inch,  you always have the work or energy m*g*d. The force to lift  mg can be half, than the distance for the force ist 2d.